# Do I need an Angularfire2 Authentication Service?

Tags: angular, authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I am currently working on a project with Angular 4 and Firebase.

Currently, in every component that needs to access Firebase Authentication, I add it to the constructor. However, it takes a bit to actually realize that the user is already logged in when it loads.

For a single-page application, this isn't much of a problem, however, I am using routing, so every time I switch a page, the new component has to be loaded from scratch.

Would making a service to handle all the authentication in the background solve this issue?

Comment: I think creating a AuthenticationService is the best way and probably the best practice

Comment: Okay. I haven't really worked with services much so I'm a little hesitant on it, but I will give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. Your authentication should be done in a service (logging in, logging out, checking auth state, etc.)
2. You should setup Guards which prevent certain routes from being accessed unless specific criteria is met (ie, user is logged in).

https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate